# ServletContext variable is not visible to other servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Let's say I have two servlets, A and B. In Servlet A I create a HashMap and store into the Servlet Context in init() like so:

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
context.setAttribute("otable", someObject);
```

Now in Servlet B's init() I am initializing a local reference to the servlet context object (I am specifying the servlet who first creates the servlet context object to start first via web.xml):

```
// get and set reference to object cache
oc = (ObjectCache)getServletContext().getAttribute("otable");
```

I then insert and size goes to 1.  When Servlet A is again called and checks the servlet context HashMap, the size is still 0.

Is it a bad idea to store a local reference to the servlet context object? I also tried getting the object from the servlet context directly but got the same result.  What am I missing here ?

The servlet who creates the shared object is started first in my web.xml with the following:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>ServletA</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>package.ServletA</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks Markus, just curious but In that case wouldn't a local variable of the servlet be the same as servlet context ?  Or is the servlet context used for multiple instances of the same servlet ?  Any issue with using a concurrent hash map for get and put across two servlet ?

Comment: I deleted my comment because it was wrong, sorry!

Comment: Are you sure your servlets are initialised? You can set load on startup. Otherwise they will not be initialised until first request arrives. Yes, definitely do not use HashMap when you expect concurrent access. It might end up in a race condition!

Comment: I edited the question to show what my web.xml entry looks like to load the initial servlet first, is this what you meant by initialized ?

Comment: I am, in the sense that it is the ServletContext, as I'm not using Spring.  Is this what you meant ?  I had thought ServletContext was where something could be put to be shared across all servlets in the web application

Comment: what do you mean by application context here as I thought in this case servlet context IS the application context.  from the doc: 


There is one context per "web application" per Java Virtual Machine. (A "web application" is a collection of servlets and content installed under a specific subset of the server's URL namespace such as /catalog and possibly installed via a .war file.)

Comment: can you give me an example of what you mean by application context ?

Comment: Forget about application Context, as I said I deleted the comment since it was wrong! Your servlet B will be initialised with the first request to servlet B not at application startup. Are there requests to servlet B?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of storing cross-servlet aka application-wide objects in the ServletContext is totally viable. I retested your approach and it works totally fine. You must missed something in your code that you forget to post.

I could make it work as followed:

ServletA (snip):

```
public void init() throws ServletException {
    Map<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    getServletContext().setAttribute("map", map);
    System.out.println("Servlet A Mapsize: " + map.size());
    map.put("foo", "bar");
    System.out.println("Servlet A Mapsize: " + map.size());
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) getServletContext().getAttribute("map");
    System.out.println("Servlet A Mapsize: " + map.size());
}
```

ServletB (snip):

```
public void init() throws ServletException {
    Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) getServletContext().getAttribute("map");
    System.out.println("Servlet B Mapsize: " + map.size());
    map.put("foo", "bar");
    System.out.println("Servlet B Mapsize: " + map.size());
}
```

web.xml (snip):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletA</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypackage.ServletA</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletB</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypackage.ServletB</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletA</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/a</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Starting the application gives you the following output:

> Servlet A Mapsize: 0
>
> Servlet A Mapsize: 1
>
> Servlet B Mapsize: 1
>
> Servlet B Mapsize: 1

As you can see, the map is correctly filled.

Now you can call servletA to check whether everything is all right.

Open in browser (my settings):

> http://localhost:8080/servtest/a

will produce the following output

> Servlet A Mapsize: 1

Btw., with CDI available you can write your applicationScoped cache producer for a more maintainable code.